# In emacs is there a way to view all user-defined key bindings?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I'm looking for a list of the ones I've defined myself, distinct from any stock bindings or bindings added by installed packages.

I've searched through help and info and haven't found anything useful. Google is surprisingly silent on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs sees no difference at all between key bindings defined by core code, those defined by third-party code you've installed, and those you've defined yourself.  There's no associated data which you can query to make that distinction.

There presumably aren't *very* many files that your custom key bindings could possibly be in, though, and you'll have a pretty good idea of what those are.

If you're at a loss, then I suggest you do this:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `rgrep` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\(define\|\(global\|local\)-set\)-key` <kbd>RET</kbd> `*.el` <kbd>RET</kbd> `~/.emacs.d/` <kbd>RET</kbd>

You can then <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd> to make the grep buffer writeable, and <kbd>M-x</kbd> `flush-lines` <kbd>RET</kbd> `/elpa/` <kbd>RET</kbd> to get rid of the packages (and similarly for anything else you don't want to include).

Comment: This is great! In my case I get relatively few results because most of my bindings are in `use-package` :bind conses, but with a little regex effort I think I can come up with something that'll work just fine. Thanks for this. I never would've gone in this direction on my own. I'm often surprised by how much you can do with emacs with a little practice and creativity, and this is one of those times.

Comment: Glad that helped.  I'll add that, depending on your config, you may find `M-x occur` or `M-x multi-occur` more convenient than `rgrep` (or `lgrep`).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the command `describe-personal-keybindings` to see only your own custom keybindings. This command will display a list of all the keybindings that you have defined yourself, either in your ~/.emacs file or in another initialization file.

Comment: This is a really good answer.